How to get x-gcp-marketplace-token in my ReactJS signup page?
I'm developing a Google Marketplace Saas Integration currently .
I'm stuck in the frontend integration as of now .
Reference : https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/integrated-saas/frontend-integration
I've created 2 pages using ReactJS i.e. Signup page and Login page and deployed my frontend code .

As we can see from the above doc snippet " When they click the button, Google Cloud sends an HTTP POST request to your sign up page, with a JSON Web Token (JWT) in the x-gcp-marketplace-token parameter. "
Google Cloud makes an HTTP POST request to my signup page ? How do I get this x-gcp-marketplace-token that Google is sending in my Signup page ???
App.jsx file code:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup/Index"
import Login from "./pages/Login/Index";
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />}/>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

Signup page code:
const Signup = () => {
  
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // signup handler 
  const handleSignup = async (values) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log("params logged :",params)
    const jwt = params.get('x-gcp-marketplace-token');
    if (!jwt) {
        alert('No JWT token found.');
        return;
    }
    dispatch(signup({...values,jwt}))
    form.resetFields()

  };


  return (
    <>
      {/* Signup form built using Ant Design */}
    </>
  )
}

export default Signup

Tried to get x-gcp-marketplace-token in my Signup page but no success .
expected to receive x-gcp-marketplace-token in url params .

You need to handle the x-gcp-marketplace-token in the HTTP POST request headers, not in the URL parameters. Since React is a frontend framework, it doesn't natively handle POST requests like a backend server would.

Use a backend service to receive the POST request from Google Cloud, and extract the JWT from the x-gcp-marketplace-token header.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.post('/api/signup', (req, res) => {
    const jwt = req.headers['x-gcp-marketplace-token'];
    if (!jwt) {
        return res.status(400).send('No JWT token found.');
    }
    res.redirect(`/signup?x-gcp-marketplace-token=${jwt}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});


Your existing React code to read the JWT from URL parameters should work.
const Signup = () => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const jwt = params.get('x-gcp-marketplace-token');
    if (!jwt) {
        alert('No JWT token found.');
        return;
    }
    // Proceed with your signup logic
};


Make sure the URL in Google Cloud is set to point to your backend endpoint (/api/signup for example).



thanks bro , I forgot to accept the answer . This is indeed the correct answer :)

it's in the request body:
const body = await req.text()
const params = new URLSearchParams(body)
const gcmJwtToken = params.get('x-gcp-marketplace-token')


const body = await req.text()
what is req ?

I was using next, so req is a NextRequest. The code is not supposed to fix your code directly. I was trying to say the x-gcp-marketplace-token is not in the url params, but in the body of the request GCP sends to your frontend.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
